# Recommended way to control layout within a beamer block?

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning, columns, beamerposter

I've used LaTeX a fair amount to write papers, but I'm just getting into `beamer` (or more specifically, `beamerposter`).

In some of my poster's blocks, I want to achieve the effect of down one side of the block (occupying maybe 75% of the width) there being some text (an itemized list), and on the right there being an `\includegraphics` image.

Is there a recommended way to achieve this sort of effect?  I'm not too clear what will work inside a block yet.  Use a `table` for layout? `multicol`? Treat it like a regular `figure` and let LaTeX place it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poster is done now; what I mainly used within blocks was `beamer`'s own `column` environment, although in a few places I used `tabular` (or `tabularx`) where I wanted to more easily line things up horizontally.  Multiple `\parbox` within a block also works well enough, although graphics within it seem to suffer from some vertical alignment problems which `columns[t]` avoids.

Things which didn't work as well as I might have hoped were `multicol` and `wrapfig`; attempting to use either invariably resulted in text exploding out of the block (although oddly the poster includes one `wrapfig` which seems to work fine).

Comment: `beamer` provides the environment `column`. However you should edit your question instead of answering.

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression column was used to arrange columns of blocks, not within blocks... will give that a try too.

Comment: Marco is right - though if it's somehow a working solution, it's fine to answer an own question.

Comment: Answer rewritten in light of actual experiences.  There do seem to be multiple possible solutions; beamer columns certainly became my default for layout within a block.